street connection from city water to sewer?
My house in Williamston County, TX has a city water connection. But this water connection is apparently driving a sewer overflow without a faucet running. The sewer pump (inside a  covered 4ft wide cement cylinder) is not functional but only floods when I turn on the city water flow.
What is driving this? I replaced the fuel pump in my pickup but I don't understand this. Turn off the water and the overflow disappears.

You need to call the county or whatever entity services your water, and point this out to them. If it is an issue they would be the ones to repair it.

Please revise your title to ask something clear and specific. It's a vague fragment with a question mark on it now. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

So, something else (not a faucet) is leaking from supply to sewer presumably without being seen.
Toilets will do that.
Water Softeners will do that, particularly if they are malfunctioning (I have considerable personal experience with that one, and after cleaning the valves a bunch resulting in temporary fixes, a new water softener sorted that house's plumbing right out.)
A malfunctioning trap primer might do that.
Certain types of filtration systems (other than softeners) may also have a potential leak path from source to sewer.
If the internal plumbing is not lacking valves, try to find out what specific item or items in the house affect the sewer outflow when shut off, (or more typically for filters/softeners, bypassed) since you already know the main valve affects it.
It's unusual to have a sewer pump if one is not needed, so it would be odd for a non-functional pump to be problem free without a leak from supply to sewer, but problematic with a leak. But the above advice stands for finding that leak.

Assuming that is actually a groundwater sump, an underground pipe leak can do that.

But the effluent is coming out of the sewer column. The water supply should NOT be even close to the sewer. That's why this makes no sense.

could be a faulty trap primer, or other leaking fixture. if it's sewer  why does it not flood with regular use?
